# What's the purpose of this community again...?

Tags: discussion, scope, new-users

I'm always confounded at how a site that tries to be as inclusive and easy to use as the Stack Exchange network, can be so unintuitive in something as simple as explaining the basic purpose of a community...

I followed [This Question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/132299/share-your-facebook-photo-album-with-non-facebook-users) from the Google, and the question had received some downvotes for apparently not being clear enough for the purpose of this community...  I had obviously joined this community sometime in the past, but not having ever posted, I thought I should refresh myself on what this community is about.

I thought, no problem, I'll just goto the front page...

[image]

Hmm, nope don't see anything here that explains the purpose of Web Applications...

Maybe I'll click "Ask Question", surely that'll give me some details about what I should be asking...

[image]

Ok, something is still missing here... I"m being told I should Ask a Good Question... But again, about what?

The best help I can get is a vague statement that

> The community is here to help you with questions about web
> applications

What is a web application?  I write web applications, and I ask my questions on StackOverflow or Database Administrators.  Is it for people who "use" web applications?

I'll give it one more try and click **how to ask a good question here**

[image]

Nope, nothing useful here... But wait, let's give it one more click before I give up...

Could the **What topics can I ask about here?** save the day?! Yes, yes after 4 clicks I can finally tell what this site is about!

Come on StackExchange.... I see post after post in meta complaining about low quality first user questions.  And there's always suggestions about how to tweak the question wizard...  Have you thought that maybe you're inviting bad post by being a little more difficult to use than you should?

Comment: I think that the same happens with other sites on [se]. Maybe this should be posted in [meta.se].

Comment: Seeing that you don't see the purpose in this site, feel free to post to Meta Stackexchange and express your views to close it down. Users have been on this site for almost a decade, this is one of the first Stack Exchange sites so obviously a lot of those were original motivated to push aren't here anymore. Posts like this definitely don't sway me one bit to figure out what you want to do about it. It doesn't feel like you're interested in actually helping just showing how much this site and to extension SE is bad at this. We get it and we know. So.. what's your solution? dangel?

Answer (score 5):

## Tour

Open https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour.

Help menu

[image: Help menu]

Website footer

[image: Footer]

The following text will be shown:

> Web Applications is a question and answer site for power users of web applications. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about web applications.

[image]

## Home page for unsigned-in users and signed-in users that have not joined Web Applications

Open https://webapps.stackexchane.com in incognito mode or sign-out of Stack Exchange. A banner will be shown with the following text:

> Web Applications Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for power users of web applications. It only takes a minute to sign up.

[image]